# F20 Unable to hibernate, /sys/power/disk disabled

Tags: fedora, hibernate

When I try to hibernate with `systemctl hibernate`, the unit `systemd-hibernate.service` enters failed state and I get the following entries in my journal:

```
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Starting Sleep.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd-sleep[2284]: Failed to write mode to /sys/power/disk: Operation not permitted
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Failed to start Hibernate.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Hibernate.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Service sleep.target is not needed anymore. Stopping.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Unit systemd-hibernate.service entered failed state.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Stopping Sleep.
Feb 09 14:18:14 pike systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
```

Indeed `cat /sys/power/disk` tells me:

```
[root@pike ~]# cat /sys/power/disk
[disabled]
```

My swap looks like this:

```
[root@pike ~]# swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0                               partition   16383996    0   -1
```

It is on the LVM and is called `/dev/fedora/swap`.

My RAM size is 16248756 bytes, so the image should fit into swap.

Suspend-to-RAM works as expected, and with other distros (Ubuntu, Arch) I was able to hibernate previously.

How can I find out why `/sys/power/disk` is [disabled]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to disable UEFI Secure Boot because I needed to use VirtualBox. Incidentally, this also enabled standby. I can now `systemctl hibernate` and `systemctl hybrid-sleep`.